# Shift select table rows

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know this question has been asked a lot but there is really no definite answer that I can find.
Here is my code.  Basically I have everything set up.  I'm just lost on where to get the rows of a table by index.  I've tried the .index function but I that's not working.  I'm trying to do something like `$('#pkgLineTable').index(i).addClass('row_selected');`

But that's not working correctly.  Any help would be great.  Thank you very much.

```
var lastSelected;

$('#pkgLineTable tr').live('click', function(event) {         

    var tableRow = $(this).closest("tr").prevAll("tr").length + 1;      
    if ($(this).hasClass('row_selected')) {
        $(this).removeClass('row_selected');       
    }
    else {           
        $(this).addClass('row_selected');         
    } 

    if (event.shiftKey) { 
        var table = $('#pkgLineTable');        


        var start = Math.min(tableRow, lastSelected);
        var end = Math.max(tableRow, lastSelected);                 

        for (var i = start; i < end; i++) {
            //$(this).parent().parent().addClass('row_selected'); 
        }

    } else {        

        lastSelected = $(this).closest("tr").prevAll("tr").length + 1;
    }
```

My start and end values are correct.  If you select the 2 row and the 5 row you get back 2 and 5.  It then iterates 2 - 5.  I need to add a class to the rows 2 - 5.

Edit I used this:

```
    for (var i = start; i < end; i++) {
            $('#pkgLineTable').each(function() {
                $(this).find("tr").eq(i).addClass('row_selected');    
            });
        }
```

That's probably not the best way to do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

instead of

```
for (var i = start; i < end; i++) {
  //$(this).parent().parent().addClass('row_selected'); 
}
```

use

```
table.find('tr:gt('+(start-1)+'):lt('+(end)+')').addClass('row_selected');
```

Comment: Thanks man.  I'll try it out.  Check my edit.  I did find something just after I posted this.

Comment: Just tried that code.  It's selecting one passed the last one I clicked.  I've tried messing with the code.  It's working slightly. Not working where I need it though.

Comment: if it's selecting 1 more than needed then use `(end-1)`

Comment: I've tried every combination of + and - 1.  Always off.  Kind of odd.

Comment: I just used this.

  for (var i = start; i < end; i++) {
                table.find("tr").eq(i).addClass('row_selected');
            }

Thanks a lot.